# How to convert from utf-8 encoding to windows-1251 while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert from utf-8 encoding to windows-1251 when the user enters text in the field

For example, the user enters: Äèíóàáó

I want to get: Aeioaao

I use a crutch of earth symbols, but I would like to find a normal method, I could not find anything working on the Internet.

What I use:

```js
$(function(){
        $('#txt').on('keyup paste change', function(){ 
        var txt = $(this), val = txt.val();
        val = val.replace(/[\u00c4]/g, 'A').replace(/[\u00e8]/g, 'e').replace(/[\u00ed]/g, 'i').replace(/[\u00f3]/g, 'o').replace(/[\u00e0]/g, 'a').replace(/[\u00e1]/g, 'a').replace(/[\u00e7]/g, 'c');
        txt.val(val);
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>paste: Äèíóàáó</p>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

It helps me, because they use the same characters in the same way. But if it's new, you need to add it.

Comment: You do realize that you totally change the meaning of words, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) the string using `NFKD` and then use regex to remove the [diacritic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes#unicodebinarypropertyname) group of chars.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#txt').on('keyup paste change', function() {
    var txt = $(this),
      val = txt.val();
    val = val
      .normalize("NFKD")
      .replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")


    txt.val(val);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>paste: Äèíóàáó</p>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

---

**With support for exceptions**

If you want to support exceptions, you can first change those to something unique, then remove the diacritics and then bring back the exceptions.

Something like

```js
const accentExceptions = [
  { char: 'Ä', uuid: crypto.randomUUID() }, 
  { char: 'ä', uuid: crypto.randomUUID() },
// crypto.randomUUID is not supported by all browsers so you 
// might want to look for an alternative to creating some unique
// text/hash for each accented character
];

function encodeExceptions(value = '') {
  let encoded = value;
  accentExceptions.forEach(({ char, uuid }) => {
    encoded = encoded.replace(new RegExp(char, 'g'), uuid);
  });
  return encoded;
}

function decodeExceptions(value = '') {
  let decoded = value;
  accentExceptions.forEach(({ char, uuid }) => {
    decoded = decoded.replace(new RegExp(uuid, 'g'), char);
  });
  return decoded;
}

function removeDiacritics(value = '') {
  return value
    .normalize("NFKD")
    .replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
}

$(function() {
  $('#txt').on('keyup paste change', function() {
    var txt = $(this),
      val = txt.val();
    val = encodeExceptions(val);
    val = removeDiacritics(val);
    val = decodeExceptions(val);
    txt.val(val);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>paste: Äèíóàáó</p>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Comment: and you can add 2 letters to the exception "Ä,ä" ?

Comment: @G-Force53 added a version that supports exceptions, with some helper methods.